# Fragments in Android Studio are stacked on top of each other in Virtual Machine

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have to turn my Unit Converter App into fragments and have it working. Everything compiles so I am able to run it in the virtual machine. The only problem is that all of the xml visuals are stacked on top of each other. I will provide code and a picture of what it looks like in my virtual machine. Please help me fix my issue so that they are not stacked on top of each other.

content_unit_converter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.plamen.unitconverter.UnitConverterActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_unit_converter">

   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/unitconverterfragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.plamen.unitconverter.UnitConverterFragment"/>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/unitcoverterdisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.plamen.unitconverter.UnitConverterDisplay"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_unit_converter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.plamen.unitconverter.UnitConverterActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_unit_converter">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TemperatureEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup">


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="From Celsius to Farenheit"
        android:id="@+id/toFarenheitRadioButton"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="From Farenheit to Celsius"
        android:id="@+id/toCelsiusRadioButton"
        android:checked="false" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Convert"
    android:id="@+id/convertButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LengthEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LengthEditText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/LengthEditText"
    android:entries ="@array/length"

    />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CONVERT"
    android:id="@+id/convertLength"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AreaEditText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:entries ="@array/area"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Convert"
    android:id="@+id/convertArea"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_unit_converter_display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.plamen.unitconverter.UnitConverterActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_unit_converter">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/TemperatureEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Enter Temperature" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/LengthEditText"
    android:hint="Enter Length"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/AreaEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/convertLength"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Enter Area" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it looks like when I run it in the Virtual Machine

[image]

This is what it looks like after I tried android: layout_below
It is also duplicated which I do not know why.

[image]

Comment: Well, both your fragments defined in `content_unit_converter.xml` are in a `RelativeLayout` and hence they're simply placed on top of each other - just like it would be with any view. You'll probably want to show only one at the time, so use a fragment transaction to hide or show the relevant fragment when required. Or, potentially better, instantiate the second fragment dynamically and add/replace it using a transaction. Alternatively, if both should be visible at the same time, just add rules to position one below the other (although a `LinearLayout` may be more suitable in that case).

Comment: How do you want the layout to look? Can you provide a mockup drawing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, whenever you use relative layout you must specify where things go. In Linear layout adding a new thing places it below/next to the previous element (depending on your orientation), but in Relative layout this doesn't happen.

So you have this:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/unitconverterfragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.plamen.unitconverter.UnitConverterFragment"

/>
<fragment
android:id="@+id/unitcoverterdisplay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.plamen.unitconverter.UnitConverterDisplay"
/>
```

In here you're just displaying 2 fragments but without saying where which one goes first.

You could add this line, or a similar:

```
android:layout_below="@id/unitconverterfragment"
```

So now you'll have this:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/unitconverterfragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.plamen.unitconverter.UnitConverterFragment"

/>
<fragment
android:id="@+id/unitcoverterdisplay"
android:layout_below="@id/unitconverterfragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.plamen.unitconverter.UnitConverterDisplay"
/>
```

You can place it below, to the right, left, on top, etc...

Comment: I added a new picture with your suggestion.

Comment: yeah...apply the same thing to the edit texts and all of the elements inside each fragment. you gotta tell the layout where you want things individually